# Counting levels of binary tree

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have SQL table for Binary tree.

Id | Name | Parent_ID |

i want to calculate 5 levels of complete binary tree for parameter node which is passed to stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In the frequent case, a binary tree with n nodes will have at least 1 + floor(log_2(n)) levels. For example, you can match 7 nodes on three levels, however 8 nodes will take at least four degrees no remember what. There are particular kinds of binary trees for which you can put better constraints on the higher restriction